# How to call a jQuery function without a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call the jQuery function below without a button click. How to do that?

jQuery:

```
  <script>
  $("#nav").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
```

In pure JavaScript I would do it like the function below, but how to do it in jQuery?

```
 function toggleWindow(){
    //alert("OK");
    }
```

Comment: in pure javascript also to call function we have to add event

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `.click()` and put it inside a self executing function:

```
(function(){
   $("#nav").toggleClass("active");
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to give the function a name? Is this correct?: `(function toggleWindow(){`

Answer (score 0):

just dont include click() event

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nav").toggleClass("active");
 });

 </script>
```

Here  , there is no need of event .As soon as DOM HTML elements are loaded ,  the script will be executed.

working fiddle [FIDDLE](
http://jsfiddle.net/Bqn5H/1/)

Comment: It's not working for the template I'm using: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html I added your code but the sidebar stays and doesn't toogle on document ready. Any ideas?

Comment: zBut fiddle working there should not be any problem. give me link to ur website to test.